# Mendeley PDF Viewer not working - Windows

Tags: windows-10, mendeley

I have downloaded **Mendeley Reference Manager** applicaition in windows-10. As seen in the screenshot below, the pdf file is available but Mendeley is not able to render it. If I open the same Pdf file in the Mendeley's web-browser version then, it works, which means that the Pdf file is available and not corrupted.

[image]

Comment: Did you try basic troubleshooting, such as restarting the device or reinstalling the app?

Comment: @Destroy666: yes, tried that and same issue. I found that some people have reported it for Ubuntu but the solution is not applicable for windows.

Comment: The common PDF viewer for Windows (Stand Alone and in Web Browser) is Adobe PDF Reader. Free.

Comment: @John: how is your comment related to the issue?

Comment: It seems to me that many people need to view PDF files (me included) and Adobe is how we do it.

Comment: Mendeley is not just for PDF viewing. It is one of the best application to organize literature review, generating citations etc.. PDF viewing is just one of its many features (because you would not like to organize literature in one app and read it another app).

Answer (score -1):

I also have faced same problem. My only solution was to delete the entry and re-import it again. And it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).